# Custom Features using scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

I am working on a project to classify short text.
One requirement I have is along with the vectorizing the short text, I will like to add additional feature like length of the text, number of url's etc as features for each input.

Is is supported in scikit-learn?
Link to any example notebook or a video with be very help.

Thanks,
Romit.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine features extracted by different transfomers (e.g. one that extracts Bag of Words (BoW) features with one that extracts other statistics) by using the [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#featureunion-combining-feature-extractors) class.

The normalization of those features and there small number with respect to the number of distinct BoW features could be problematic. Whether or not this is problem depends on the assumptions made by the models trained downstream and on the specific data and target task.

Comment: Normalization can still be performed by a union of `TfidfVectorizer(norm='l2')` and `make_pipeline(DictVectorizer(sparse=False), StandardScaler())` (in scikit-learn 0.15 syntax). Although for non-negative features, L2 normalization after the union should be fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used FeatureUnion class. However my approach was simpler and rather straight forward.  Extract the features from your custom pipeline and append it with what you extracted from scikit-learn pipeline. This is nothing but appending array in numpy/scipy.

Precautions:
a) You must remember what are the feature-id's extracted from your custom pipeline. This will help you in appending arrays, without mixing things.
b)You would have to do normalization(as required) of your custom pipeline features.

Solution:
Write a custom feature extractor class. Wrap functionality like feature extraction, normalization etc into it.

Comment: Manual feature stacking is possible but then it's painful to properly evaluate the full model via cross-validation and do parameter tuning with grid search. The FeatureUnion class behaves as a regular transformer and therefore can be used in a scikit-learn pipeline to do cross validation and grid search.