# python:scikit-learn How to combine different text features e.g. bow & pos

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I want to use different text features for scikit learn classifiers like SVM. I want to combine features like bag of words, temporal features.  How can combine these and pass to classifier.

I wont be able to use FeatureUnion, as it requires input data be same on all the transform.

e.g.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii',
                        tokenizer=nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize,
X_feat = tfidf.fit_transform(X_data)
```

I have other feature which are not directly depend on same data e.g. if sentence starts with Wh Question

```
whqwords = ['who','how','where', 'what', 'why', 'when', 'which','whom']

tokens=nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent)
if (tokens[0] in whqwords) :            
            features[tokens[0]] = True
```

Now how can I combine X_feat & features and pass to a classifier?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609588/custom-features-using-scikit-learn. You can use a union of vectorizers to achieve what you want. Alternatively, switch to `DictVectorizer` to get full control over feature extraction.

Comment: thanks DictVectorizer worked for me.